# Get overflow text from OpenPDF

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, openpdf

I'm trying to set up a page where the text fills up in a text box and then overflows to another text box on the page. I set up a rectangle and will send it the text, but I can't figure out how to find the text that won't fit.

I remember seeing a function that adds words to a document (or table or something) and it had a "Returns remaining text" feature. I can't find that function anymore.

How can I get the text that won't fit returned so I can assign it to a variable to send to the next textbox?

Comment: Have a look at the `ColumnText` class.

Comment: I didn’t see it. The “go()” function only retires a bool for if it ran out of text or space to write. I need the actual text it hasn’t written yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `ColumnText` which can be used to render text inside a defined shape. The `go()` method returns the constants `NO_MORE_TEXT` (1) if the text fit inside the shape or `NO_MORE_COLUMN` (2) if the text is overflowing. As far as I know there is no way to actually get the remaining text directly. However, you don't need the text for rendering it in the next textbox.

In case the text overflows, you can just assign a new column and call `go()` again. Repeat this process until all the text has been drawn.

Here is an example with 3 simple rectangular boxes:

```java
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("overflow.pdf"));
document.open();

// define text
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
ct.addElement(new Paragraph(LOREM_IPSUM)); // <- some filler text from constant

// fill first box
ct.setSimpleColumn(50, 735, 400, 800);
int result = ct.go();

// fill second box (if necessary)
if (result == ColumnText.NO_MORE_COLUMN) {
    ct.setSimpleColumn(75, 635, 425, 700);
    result = ct.go();
}

// fill third box (if necessary)
if (result == ColumnText.NO_MORE_COLUMN) {
    ct.setSimpleColumn(100, 535, 450, 600);
    result = ct.go();
}

document.close();
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Cool. I was trying to find the remaining text because I wanted the second text box to by dynamic. I had two columns of text, add I wanted the larger one to full under the smaller one (kind of like an L of that makes any sense). Because one of the columns will also go fully across on top, I needed the remaining text of that column in order to see if the remaining text is longer than the other column. (I was going to use .go(true) and then see which has more lines). If you can think of a better way to do this, I’d be grateful if you could tell me.

Comment: @Doragon I don't fully understand how these columns and boxes in your comment above work together. Maybe you could formulate this as a new question. It would be good to show an illustration how exactly it should look like in the PDF. I have the feeling this can be solved in a better way, especially if you want to float/wrap around some object.